# Jquery: run function only every x seconds

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a rather performance intensive resize function that I can't run normally as it would clutter the browser. I have decided to let the function run no more than once every 500ms, like this:

```
var resizeRunning = 0;
window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
    if (resizeRunning == 0) {
        resizeRunning = 1;
        $(".freebies_tile").each(function() {
            $(this).waypoint(function() {
                var el = this;
                $(el).removeClass('not_loaded');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(el).removeClass('not_active');
                }, 500);
            }, { offset: '100%', context: '.content_div', triggerOnce: true  });
        }); 
        setTimeout(function() {
            resizeRunning = 0;
        }, 500);
    }
}, true);
```

This works, but I wonder if there's a shorter\faster way to achieve the same result.

Comment: `setTimeout()` is the best solution.

Comment: This is perfectly fine.

Comment: setTimeout() is the correct option, but why are you setting the timeout for each tile obj? are you looking for a progressive hiding effect? You could improve your performance if you save the $(".freebies_tile") in a var outside the eventHandler.

Comment: I second that notion.  Scanning the DOM on every iteration will add up when you have many elements.

Comment: FYI, when you have working code and you want ways to improve it, there's a forum just for that situation at http://codereview.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks to everyone for the feedback. I moved the $(".freebies_tile") in an external variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the way you want your resize logic it to run no more often than every 500ms and you don't want to ever miss any resize processing, you can do something like this.

This has an advantage over yours that if a resize event comes in within 500ms since the last time you processed it, but then there are no more, this will still process that resize event.  Your code will miss those last resize events because they were too soon after the last one and you won't ever process the final size.

```
// closure to store state variables without making globals
(function() {
    var lastResizeProcessTime = 0;
    var resizeTimer;
    // don't call this more often than every 500ms
    var minResizeTime = 500;
    window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
        var delta = new Date().getTime() - lastResizeProcessTime;
        // if it's been a while since last resize, just do it now
        if (delta >= minResizeTime) {
            processResize();
        } else {
            // if resize not already scheduled, schedule one for 
            // minResizeTime from the last one
            if (!resizeTimer) {
                resizeTimer = setTimeout(processResize, minResizeTime - delta);
            }
        }        
    }, true);

    function processResize() {
        lastResizeProcessTime = new Date().getTime();
        clearTimeout(resizeTimer);
        resizeTimer = null;
        $(".freebies_tile").each(function() {
            $(this).waypoint(function() {
                var el = this;
                $(el).removeClass('not_loaded');
                setTimeout(function() {
                    $(el).removeClass('not_active');
                }, minResizeTime);
            }, { offset: '100%', context: '.content_div', triggerOnce: true  });
        }); 
    }
})();
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/v4xm6Lar/

---

It is a separate issue whether you should or should not be doing as much DOM traversal every time you process a resize.  We would need to know more about the context of your app and what could change between resize operations to know whether you should or could cache some of the DOM info from one call to the next.

Comment: Wow, thanks for the insightful answer. You're perfectly right in pointing out that my code will miss resize events that happen while my function is in cooldown. I'm still not sure wheter i'll use my code or yours as is seems a bit overkill for what i'm trying to achieve, but this is definitely the correct answer.